# Best way to let browsers refresh from cache on a live website?

Tags: css, image, browser-cache

It's about making changes in design (css-files and images) on a website which is already online and in use. I wonder what is the best-practice to make sure that visitors see the changes without clearing there browser's cache manually. Things that came in my mind:

- change meta-tag - dismissed because I do not want the site to be ALWAYS loaded from the server
- include the css-file with a parameter (like timestamp) after made a change
- change the names of included images so that they are reloaded - means also change names in the files where images are included
- ?

What else could achieve the loading from server? Did I forget some advantages/disadvantages?

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of this post: [How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers)

My favoured solution is to set a random number after you call the file e.g.

```
css/styles.ccs?628454548

images/sprite.gif?8356484894
```

You could use javascript/php or whatever to set those random numbers every time the page is called to the browser.

Comment: Sry I did not found this question. My issue is not about loading the files EVERY TIME, I do want to have files cached by the visitor's browsers in general. I just want to say, after making changes, "now reload the files from the server". So the paramater on image-URLs also works in all browsers? I wasn't that sure. Thanks for your answer.